# Is INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger the best option

Tags: t-sql

I have to check when a table is inserted to/updated to see if a column value exists for the same HotelID and different RoomNo in the same table. I'm thinking that an INSTEAD OF trigger on the table would be a good option, but I read that it's a bad idea to update/insert the table the trigger executes on inside the trigger and you should create the trigger on a view instead (which raises more questions for me)

Is it ok to create a trigger like this? Is there a better option?

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tgr_tblInterfaceRoomMappingUpsert
   ON  dbo.tblInterfaceRoomMapping
   INSTEAD OF  INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @txtRoomNo nvarchar(20)

    SELECT @txtRoomNo = Sonifi_RoomNo 
    FROM dbo.tblInterfaceRoomMapping r 
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i
    ON r.iHotelID = i.iHotelID 
    AND r.Sonifi_RoomNo = i.Sonifi_RoomNo 
    AND r.txtRoomNo <> i.txtRoomNo

    IF @txtRoomNo IS NULL
    BEGIN
       -- Insert/update the record
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
       -- Raise error
    END

END
GO
```

Comment: What type of data duplication are you attempting to prevent? I would usually say you should be using unique indexes to prevent data duplication, not triggers with an error.

Comment: We need to make sure the Sonifi_RoomNo is not duplicated for a different RoomNo with the same iHotelID. For instance, the table has a record where HotelID = 123, RoomNo = 200 and Sonifi_RoomNo = 200. We can't insert a record where HotelID = 123, RoomNo = 201 and Sonifi_RoomNo = 200 because Sonifi_RoomNo 200 is already assigned to RoomNo 200. Is there a way to accomplish that without using a trigger?

Answer (score 2):

So it sounds like you only want 1 row per combo of HotelID and Sonifi_RoomNo.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_dbo_tblInterfaceRoomMapping
ON dbo.tblInterfaceRoomMapping(HotelID,Sonifi_RoomNo)
```

Now if you try and put a second row with the same values, it will bark at you.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. I'll test it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's (usually) *not* okay to create a trigger like that.

Your trigger assumes a single row update or insert will only ever occur - is that guaranteed?

What will be the value of `@txtRoomNo` if multiple rows are inserted or updated in the same batch?

Eg, if an update is performed against the table resulting in 1 row with correct data and 1 row with incorrect data, how do you think your trigger would cope in that situation? Remember triggers fire once **per insert/update**, not **per row**.

Depending on your requirments you could keep the instead of trigger concept, however I would suggest a separate trigger for inserts and for updates.

In each you can then insert / update and include a `where not exists` clause to only allow valid inserts / updates, ignoring inserting or updating anything invalid.

I would avoid raising an error in the trigger, if you need to handle bad data you could also insert into some logging table with the reverse `where exists` logic and then handle separately.

Ultimately though, it would be best for the application to check if the roomNo is already used.